# Animate container height, add ... to last word in paragraph

Tags: jquery, css, height, jquery-animate

I have a div.infotext with one paragraph inside. I animate the height of that div to a 120px. So there is more text below, which is not shown, as the height cuts it off.

The whole text appears when i hover that div.

The issue i'm having now is, that there is no indicator that there is more text inside this paragraph. I'd like to add three dots ( ... ) at the end of the last word that is shown, and to disappear when i'm hovering the div.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:** Added the code.

```
function enableHoverQuotes(){

var height3 = $('.c2244').height();
$('.introtext').css({ height: '107px', overflow: 'hidden' });

$(".introtext").hoverIntent(showInfoText,hideInfoText);

function showInfoText(){ $(this).animate({'height':height3}, 600); }
function hideInfoText(){ $(this).animate({'height':'107'}, 600); }

}
```

Comment: We need code... We need code... We need code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `<p>...</p>` to bottom right of the div with absolute positioning and hide it on hover. This will look to the user like the text ist actually cut of. Example:

```
CSS:
.more {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 background: #fff;
}

.container {
 position:relative;
 height:120px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

HTML:
<div class="container">
 <p>Fill in a lot of text here</p>
 <p class="more">...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS3 provides text-overflow property where you can define what you want to happen when text overflows the containing element. Browser support is there in all major browsers- you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow

What you ought to do is to add text-overflow property to your introtext css

Answer (score 2):

Add this css...

```
div.infotext
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

That will add the ... at the end of the div, *if* there's more text.  Your previous show/hide code will still work without affecting this.

Comment: I like this one, but as far as I know browser support for text-overflow is pretty bad.

Comment: text-overflow is supported in most browsers as long as it's used in conjunction with clip or ellipsis, so it's fine for this.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to just append a floating div to the bottom right of the parent div if scrollHeight is greater than height

The code might look something like:

```
if ($(element)[0].scrollHeight > $(element).height()) {
  $(element).append('<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0" id="overflow">...</siv>');
}
```

and then have a toggle on id="overflow" to hide it when the div is expanded.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/M5rzC/4/